# My java program doesn't create a window but has no syntax errors

Tags: java

I'm having problems creating a window for a game:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2865542191528057205L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH /12*9;

    public game(){
        new window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a game!", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){


    }

    public void run(){

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){



    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class window extends Canvas{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1523596471284190399L;

    public window(int width, int height, String title, game game){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }


}
```

Comment: What DOES happen? You can't just copy paste your code, and let us figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something in your `main` method.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11529069)

Comment: I was able to see only one question: "My program does compile without syntax errors, but it does not do anything. How can I fix this." I think I provided a reasonable answer to this question.